# Should soft-deleting be modeled in the domain layer?

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, soft-delete

Should soft deleting be modeled in a DDD entity, or should the repository's delete method do this by itself without burdening the domain model with it?

I can't tell if this is a business logic or technical concern.

If it is a domain layer concern where a flag is set or a status is changed on the entity, would that mean any object that can be soft deleted is an entity and not a value object since it implies the object has a life cycle?

A soft deleted object would also need to be shown in certain queries with the ability to undelete them. Does this suggest it is business logic and belongs in the domain layer?

Would you also handle soft deleting and undeleting by changing a flag on the entity and calling the update method on the repository? Or have separate delete/undelete methods on the repository?

Answer (score 3):

Its an excellent question,

It belongs to the repository, technically, your client does not care how the delete is done. Even if you are working in a bank where keeping record is a requirement, both legal and compliant, this can be viewed as a technical concern.

However, it also belongs to the model: On the domain side, there is nothing wrong having a property called "archived", "removed", "deleted" or the like, which can be put back to false when you want to un-delete. Such property could be checked as a pre-condition for applying commands on your object, such as throwing errors if trying to modify an attribute of an archived entity.

Sometimes the lines are blurred, and there is no perfect answer, remember there is no good or bad models, only useful models.